# Calculating error percentage for rolling dice

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm trying to figure out how an error percentage is calculated when rolling 2 6-sided dice.

The table I am looking at shows the sum of the dice, the actual number of times a sum was rolled, the odds, and the error(as a percentage).

They claim they are getting the error by taking the difference of the odds and the actual roll.  But I've tried this, and it doesn't seem to calculate the way shown.

For example, this table:

```
Sum:    Rolled:     TheOdds:      The Error:
   2          0            1            100%
   3          1            2             50%
   4          1            3             66%
   5          7            4             75%
   6          6            5             20%
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how they are getting the values under the error column.

Is there a formula for calculating these error percentages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TheOdds is the number of times you expect to get the associated Sum in 36 trials. E.g. For Sum = 2 (i.e. two $1s$) we expect it to happen once in $36$ times.

The formula you want is:

$$\text{Error} = \dfrac{\vert \text{Rolled} - \text{TheOdds}\vert }{\text{TheOdds}}\times 100\%.$$

E.g. For Sum=$3$:

$$\text{Error} = \dfrac{\vert 1 - 2\vert }{2}\times 100\% = 50\%.$$